# List Only The Active SELinux Booleans

Tags: centos, rhel, selinux

I just want to know how i can list only the active or [ on ] SELinux Booleans in CentOS 8.2

when i type `semanage boolean -l` it gives me all the available booleans and of course it's default state and the current state.

But I just want to list all the `(on  ,  on)` or the `(off  ,  off)` Booleans.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`semanage boolean -l -C`

Should do the trick.

I've actually written an awk script to do that before finally checking man :-)

`semanage boolean -l | awk '{vs=$2; vd=$4; gsub(/\(/,"",vs); gsub(/\)/,"",vd); if (vs!=vd) print}'`

Comment: Actually, I've tried `semanage boolean -l -C` but it gives me the booleans that I've turned them on 

But not all the other active booleans by default.

Comment: Update. I've tried this with simple regex like this
`semanage boolean -l | grep -i "(on"`